# Can't get Firestore Rules get() to work inside a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firestore doesn't work well with **get** inside a function

I have this rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isProjectOpenForAssign() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(anyProject)).data.canAssignTask == true;
    }

    match /projects/{anyProject} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;

      match /tasks/{anyTask} {
        allow create: if request.auth != null && (isProjectOpenForAssign());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When running the simulator testing it I get:

> Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [23], column [14]. Function not found error: Name: [get].; Error: Invalid argument provided to call. Function: [get], Argument: ["||invalid_argument||"]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the scope of where you define your function. Since you define `isProjectOpenForAssign` at the same level as this match `match /projects/{anyProject}`, the function won't have access to `anyProject`.

There are two solutions:

1. Pass `anyProject` as a parameter to `isProjectOpenForAssign`.

   ```
   function isProjectOpenForAssign(anyProject) {
     return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(anyProject)).data.canAssignTask == true;
   }

   match /projects/{anyProject} {
     allow create: if request.auth != null;

     match /tasks/{anyTask} {
       allow create: if request.auth != null && (isProjectOpenForAssign(anyProject));
     }
   }
   ```
2. Define the function inside the match that declares `anyProject`.

   ```
   match /projects/{anyProject} {
     function isProjectOpenForAssign() {
       return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(anyProject)).data.canAssignTask == true;
     }

     allow create: if request.auth != null;

     match /tasks/{anyTask} {
       allow create: if request.auth != null && (isProjectOpenForAssign());
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Such a weird error message. how about: `"anyProject" variable is not available. If you are using a function - make sure you pass it`

Comment: While the message is fairly generic and basic, it was pretty clear to me.